wxwidgets minimal works on local display but not on x terminal
I have two wxwidgets hosts:

Windows 11 VirtualBox 7.0.14 161095 Fedora 39 (guest) wxWidgets 3.2.4
Fedora 39 (native) wxWidgets 3.2.4

The vbox host will play to an MobaXterm Personal Edition v24.0 5204 aka vbox-x-server. The native-x-server will not. The native host will play to its own local display.
The native-x-server will just stop without elaborating a window or dumping messages. This includes but is probably not limited to:

wxwidgets sample "minimal"
wxglade
wxGlade sample "bare bones"

The library is clearly attempting to access the X server. If you bypass the ssh tunnelling, then MobaXterm will pop up a dialog asking if you allow the application to access it. However, no windows show up.
I'm trying to migrate from the vbox environment to the native environment.
Is there some magic environment twiddle that might illume the problem?
I'm trying to avoid building wxWidgets to debug this problem. I've straced the apps without any usable information revealing itself.

what does dmesg and syslog says? Any logging on the MobaXterm?

dmesg looks to be silent on the matter. If there is logging on MobaXterm I haven't located it.

can you try to run it under gdb? Or try to start the sample by double clicking in the "Explorer"?

I managed to build wxWidgets/samples/minimal with debugging symbols and ran it in gdb. It looks to stall reading a file descriptor in the GTK main loop. Which could be anything.

@Nufosmatik, what is your version of GTK? And you should try to build wxWidgets master - it’s easy and fast.

That's "nufosmatic" as in National UFO Sighting Mapping, Analysis, and Tracking Information Cybersite (nufosmatic.infinityfreeapp.com)... FC 39 comes with 3.2.4- since "minimal" demonstrates the problem, building is probably not a huge burden...

Sorry, gtk3-3.24.41-1...

Looks to be one of the Wayland vs X11 problems reported. GDK_BACKEND=x11 environment works around the problem if not fixes it.

And some time in the past (from Fedora 25 to 39) I added an alias in ~/.aliases - the new system I gen'd up from scratch:



alias python="GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/python3"
alias xrced="GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/xrced"
alias wxglade="GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/wxglade"
alias egrep="grep -E --binary-files=text"
alias llog='ls -1t logs/*.log | head -1'

On the system where wxWidgets wxglade was working:
[me@williams ~]$ which wxglade
alias wxglade='GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/wxglade'

On the system where wxWidgets wxglade was not working:
[me@vesper ~]$ which wxglade
/usr/bin/wxglade

Eliciting the GDK_BACKEND=x11 fixes the problem everywhere else I've tried.
[me@vesper temp]$ python bare.py # this gets you no app

[me@vesper temp]$ GDK_BACKEND=x11 python bare.py # this gets you an app

This looks like one of the many Wayland vs X11 problems.
I think I'm fixed for now.
